# find specific folder in any mapped drive and report its full UNC path

Tags: batch-file, find, directory, unc

I was wondering if it was possible using a batch file to find a specific folder in any mapped drive of a PC and have it report the folders full UNC path. Lets say a PC has drives mapped of N:\ & S:\ (or any usual network drive letter for that matter). The folder could be in either folder and I run some code to find where the folder is, it will be in the root of the drive share (avoiding need for recursive subfolder scanning) e.g. N:\Special_Folder however, the end result of the code will report the FULL UNC e.g.

Folder Found!..

\server-vm01\data\shared_area\special_folder

Hope that makes sense. I have tried with some code I already use to identify a USB stick, but am having difficulty porting it to the needs above. Any pointers would be great, thank you.

```
for %%a in (d: e: f: g: h: i: j: k: l: m: n: o: p: q: r: s: t: u: v: w: x: y: z:) do | find "special_folder" >nul && set unc=%%a:
echo %unc%
pause
```

edit for troubleshoot, output net use

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Admin>net use
New connections will be remembered.

```
Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           Y:        \\DISKSTATION\NetBackup   Microsoft Windows Network
OK           Z:        \\DISKSTATION\NetBackup   Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.


C:\Users\Admin>
```

I tried to fix and I got as far as trying FOR /F "tokens=2-3 delims= " in the first line and that removes the Microsoft Windows Networ but then drops a letter out the path e.g \DISKSTATION\NetBacku\specialfolder

also If I run as admin, as will need to, the code doesn't echo any path, does non admin ? Thanks

***EDIT*** **(final)**

Thank you both for these really helpful codes. I shall edit the original question with what works, both do as it happens, but I can only tick one solution by the looks of it.

Test Environment:-

**Win10 (UAC is ON)**

**Win7 (UAC is off)**

Two Mapped Drives in each with a test Folder called Daphne in root of just one of the 2 drives.

```
    @echo off
    FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%G IN ('"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=4 get name,providername /format:csv"') do (
       FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%H IN ("%%G") DO (
           IF EXIST "%%I\Daphne\" echo %%I\Daphne
        )
     )
pause
```

The above works perfectly on the Win7 (UAC is off) test system, Admin or not. Works as non Admin Win10 (UAC is ON), **doesn't** work running as "Admin" though.

Below **worked everywhere** regardless of admin or not, in both environments.

The original code suggested works fine (FYI) but I just needed it to output the path with no quotations or additional texts, so I am just adding the authors generous efforts (tweaked slightly) to conclude the original question in line with my original intentions.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_FolderToSearch=Daphne"                  
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('reg query "HKCU\Network"') do (
  for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%f in ('reg query "%%~D" /v RemotePath ^| find /I "RemotePath"') do (
    if exist "%%~h\%_FolderToSearch%\" echo %%~h\%_FolderToSearch%
  )
)
pause
```

Below is the output on the screen from both code snippets in their working forms:-

```
\\DISKSTATION\NetBackup\Daphne
Press any key to continue . . .

\\DISKSTATION\NetBackup\Daphne
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I can now easily set this as a path statement in a config file to completely automate client software installations by having the customer just tell me the folder name of where they want our data on their network. I shall test first and report back.

Thankyou!

Comment: If they are mapped drives you are searching then use the NET USE command.

Comment: I am familiar with that but not sure how to incorporate into a find folder routine?  Thanks

Comment: So they changed the output for Windows 10.

Comment: So you can now see how things can spiral out of control when you don't provide enough details up front about your problem.

Comment: Problems only became apparent when trying to execute the code though.  If I knew UAC blocked net use commands I would have happily stated something along the lines as such right back at the start.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to "Prompt for credentials" in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035277).

Next code snippet should work **even from an elevated command prompt**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "_FolderToSearch=models"                  folder name to be searched for

echo no recursion: folder in the root of the drive share:

for /F "delims=" %%D in ('reg query "HKCU\Network"') do (
  for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%f in ('reg query "%%~D" /v RemotePath ^| find /I "RemotePath"') do (
    if exist "%%~h\%_FolderToSearch%\" echo # FOUND [%%~nD:] "%%~h\%_FolderToSearch%"
  )
)

echo recursive search:

for /F "delims=" %%D in ('reg query "HKCU\Network"') do (
  for /F "tokens=1,2,*" %%f in ('reg query "%%~D" /v RemotePath ^| find /I "RemotePath"') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%# in ('dir /B /S /AD "%%~h\%_FolderToSearch%*" 2^>NUL') do (
        if /I "%%~nx#"=="%_FolderToSearch%" echo # found [%%~nD:] "%%~#"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: @Squashman nice solution (does not search in subfolders) but **1**. query for _key property_  `DeviceID` instead of `name` and **2**. add some propperty e.g. `SystemName` to keep clear of _Carriage Return_ problem. Try  `…  get DeviceID, providername, SystemName /format:csv`.

Comment: My original code searched sub folders but then the user told me they did not want to do that. **it will be in the root of the drive share (avoiding need for recursive subfolder scanning)**

Answer (score 1):

I was way over thinking the code.  Using WMIC and a simple IF EXIST should work.

```
 FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%G IN ('"wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=4 get name,providername /format:csv"') do (
    FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%H IN ("%%G") DO (
        IF EXIST "%%I\SpecialFolder\" echo %%I\SpecialFolder
    )
 )
 pause
```

Comment: Holy Moly, you pretty much nailed it!! It needs a tiny tweak if possible. Firstly it scanned through sub folders, if its possible to just search root of the mapped drives? appreciate your efforts very much.

Comment: @Tika9o9, that actually simplifies the code a lot and makes it run much faster.  I totally overlooked your specifications in your question.  My apologies.  I will be right back with new code.

Comment: no worries bro, I had a disconnected drive when I tested and that caused the "cant find drive error" so ignore that my bad. Just the tweak to the folder search now, thanks!!!

Comment: Impressive. Seriously impressive. Thanks very much. See I can now use that as a variable and use it in a config file. So by having a predefined folder somewhere on a share my installation can be practically fully automated and configured with the UNC loaded automatically!!!

Comment: I'm going to add the code to my existing script, which doesn't have setlocal delayed on it? Its fairly basic, should I add it to the whole script now or just leave it added as starting when this new code runs? thanks !!

Comment: @Tika9o9, I added a second set of code to find the folder in only the root directory.  I also made both search case insensitive.  Please update your batch file with my latest code.

Comment: @Tika9o9 The `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is needed for the `UNC` variable. The UNC path had a hanging space at the end of the variable so I needed to remove it so that the full path looked correct. When you are inside a code block, you need to use delayed expansion for your variables when you are manipulating them.

Comment: Thanks!! Seem to have a problem its including some text from the net use command in the path ...\\DISKSTATION\Downloads   Microsoft Windows Networ\specialfolder...was okay previous...?

Comment: @Tika9o9, the find command should only be finding lines with a \\ in it.  The **Microsoft Windows Network** wording is on its own line in my `NET USE` output.  Are you saying that wording is on the same line in your `'NET USE` output?

Comment: yes all on one line.  was fine first few tries just reported the location now I mapped a new drive to test seems to have gone awry :(

Comment: also if I run as administrator it breaks it, doesn't show the path anymore :_( ? Hope you can fix it.

Comment: @Tika9o9, please edit your question and show me the output from the `NET USE` command.

Comment: @Tika9o9, I tested my script with running as administrator and I still get the same output.  So they may have changed a lot of things with Windows 10.

Comment: I run in a win7 VM and I get the output mixed in with the path like on 10 .....\\DISKSTATION\NetBackup   Microsoft Windows Networ\Daphne