# .bat file to replace network drives

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am overseeing a server update, moving network drives from an outdated server to a new one. A large number of relatively tech illiterate employees will need to remap network drives. In order to make the transition as simple as possible, I would like to be able to provide a .bat that will do the following:

1. Determine what network drives the user has mapped.
2. Determine which of the drives match ones that are to be updated.
3. Replace the outdated drives with the new ones.
4. Delete the outdated maps.

I know how to use the "net use" commands to determine the drives, create maps, and delete them. The issue I am running into is that I am unsure how to ensure that each user gets only the network drives that they already had mapped. Some users may not have permissions for all the drives and I don't want to just map all ~10 of them. Most users will only have one or two.

I would like to keep this as simple as possible, so something built-in to windows would be preferable.

---

EDIT:

The For does return the values I am looking for. Below is some pseudocode that hopefully describes what I want to achieve with this I am uncertain as to how to either put all these commands within the For or how to set variables for the results of every loop.

```
@echo off
echo Finding all \\oldServer drives
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims= " %%G in ('net use ^|find "\\oldServer"') do @echo "%%G" "%%H" 
::if user has oldDrive1 mapped, map newDrive1
if %%H==\\oldServer\oldDrive1 net use * \\newServer\newDrive1 /persistent:yes
::if user has oldDrive1 mapped, remove that map
if %%H==\\oldServer\oldDrive1 net use %%G /delete
::if user has oldDrive2 mapped, map newDrive2
if %%H==\\oldServer\oldDrive2 net use * \\newServer\newDrive2 /persistent:yes
::if user has oldDrive2 mapped, remove that map
if %%H==\\oldServer\oldDrive2 net use %%G /delete
pause
```

---

EDIT:

I was able to figure out something that works. It is far from elegant, but it works.

```
@echo off
set old1=\\oldServer\oldDrive1
set old2=\\oldServer\oldDrive2
set old3=\\oldServer\oldDrive3
set old4=\\oldServer\oldDrive4
set old5=\\oldServer\oldDrive5
set old6=\\oldServer\oldDrive6
set old7=\\oldServer\oldDrive7
set old8=\\oldServer\oldDrive8
set old9=\\oldServer\oldDrive9
set new1=\\newServer\newDrive1
set new2=\\newServer\newDrive2
set new3=\\newServer\newDrive3
set new4=\\newServer\newDrive4
set new5=\\newServer\newDrive5
set new6=\\newServer\newDrive6
set new7=\\newServer\newDrive7
set new8=\\newServer\newDrive8
set new9=\\newServer\newDrive9
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims= " %%G in ('net use ^|find "\\oldServer"') do (
    @echo %%G %%H
    if /I %%H==%old1% net use * %new1% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old2% net use * %new2% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old3% net use * %new3% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old4% net use * %new4% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old5% net use * %new5% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old6% net use * %new6% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old7% net use * %new7% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old8% net use * %new8% /persistent:yes
    if /I %%H==%old9% net use * %new9% /persistent:yes
    net use %%G /delete
)
exit
```

Thank you for your assistance, this would have taken a lot longer without it.

---

EDIT:

The suggestion to move the /delete function was taken, I was unsure if the /delete would reset the %%G and %%H variables, but this works a little cleaner.

```
@echo off
set old1=\\oldServer\oldDrive1
set old2=\\oldServer\oldDrive2
set old3=\\oldServer\oldDrive3
set old4=\\oldServer\oldDrive4
set old5=\\oldServer\oldDrive5
set old6=\\oldServer\oldDrive6
set old7=\\oldServer\oldDrive7
set old8=\\oldServer\oldDrive8
set old9=\\oldServer\oldDrive9
set new1=\\newServer\newDrive1
set new2=\\newServer\newDrive2
set new3=\\newServer\newDrive3
set new4=\\newServer\newDrive4
set new5=\\newServer\newDrive5
set new6=\\newServer\newDrive6
set new7=\\newServer\newDrive7
set new8=\\newServer\newDrive8
set new9=\\newServer\newDrive9
for /F "tokens=2-3 delims= " %%G in ('net use ^|find "\\oldServer"') do (
   @echo %%G %%H
   net use %%G /delete
   if /I %%H==%old1% net use %%G %new1% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old2% net use %%G %new2% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old3% net use %%G %new3% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old4% net use %%G %new4% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old5% net use %%G %new5% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old6% net use %%G %new6% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old7% net use %%G %new7% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old8% net use %%G %new8% /persistent:yes
   if /I %%H==%old9% net use %%G %new9% /persistent:yes    
)
exit
```

Comment: Start with `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims= " %G in ('net use ^|find "\\"') do @echo "%G" "%H" "%I"` (see https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880912/). Then,  [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: How about moving the `net use %%G /delete` up before the first `if` and replacing `*` with `%%G` in the `if` lines to preserve the correct drive letters?